# playing a sound/notification in finch over ssh on my local machine

Tags: ssh, bash, audio

So I have `finch`, a command line chat client (think pidgin) running on a remote machine that I `ssh` into. `finch` has notification sounds and can run a command when certain events occur, letting you pass the sound file in as `%s`. e.g. `mplayer %s`

from the remote machine, when the notification occurs, what kind of command could I run to play whatever `%s` is on my local machine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use *pulse-audio* as sound server, you can use `module-native-protocol-tcp` to accept tcp connection from your remote machine.

In the following example, I use an ssh tunnel to forward the audio request from remote machine to the local one.

On the local machine, do something like:

```
pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1
ssh -R 9999:127.0.0.1:4713 you@remotehost
```

then on remote machine you can use `paplay`

```
paplay -s 127.0.0.1:9999 soundfile.wav
```

***ADDED*** I discovered that `auth-ip-acl` does not accept `localhost` as a valid parameter, you have to use `127.0.0.1` (or whatever your machine uses localhost address).

***EDIT*** It should be `ssh -R`, not `ssh -L` (we are forwarding a remote port to a local port).

---

If you have an old version of pulse-audio (pre 0.9.3), you can use cookie based authorization.

```
pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-anonymous=1 auth-cookie-enabled=0
scp ~/.pulse-cookie you@remotehost:
ssh -R 9999:localhost:4713 you@remotehost
```

Obviously, you can simply do not use any authentication in pulse-audio but I can not recommend you this solution. Use, at least, a firewall to avoid remote connections.

Comment: getting "Failure: Module initialization failed" on `pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=localhost`. Am I missing a dependency or something?

Comment: Try `pulseaudio --check ; echo $?` to check if pulseaudio server is running. It should print `0` if running.

Comment: On my machine (opensuse 12.1), the module is in `/usr/lib64/pulse-1.1/modules/module-native-protocol-tcp.so`. Which distribution are you running on?

Comment: my local machine echos `0` properly.. remote is on ubuntu 11.10 and my local is on 11.04. i tried referencing the module directly on my local


`pactl load-module /usr/lib/pulse-0.9.22/modules/module-native-protocol-tcp.so auth-ip-acl=localhost`

and I get `Failure: Invalid argument`. Any idea? (btw thanks for helping)

Comment: `auth-ip-acl` is supported since version 0.9.3. See http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules#module-native-protocol

Comment: @tester, try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and let me know ...

Comment: hmm I tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1, the cookie auth version and was unable to get it working.. highly likely that it was user error on my part.. I think I just need to upgrade ubuntu and get the latest pulse audio setup to do what you originally said.